# Implement Cipher in Nodejs and Express

Tags: python, node.js, express, encryption

So, I'm going to be having a service that posts fields to my app and have to do the following:

> When an action occurs within your account, several values are passed
>   along in the Instant Notification query string (see URL Parameters).
>   While building the string we create a sha1, or a hash of the values
>   passed, and your Secret Key. The result is the cverify parameter. Upon
>   receipt of the query string parameters, your system must also create a
>   sha1, or a hash of the values passed, and your Secret Key.
>
> The validity of the data received is evaluated by using the cverify
>   parameter we send and the value produced in your system. Only if there
>   is an exact match between the two values can you be certain the
>   information received has not been tampered with.

I'm guessing I should use the `crypto` module. But, not sure how to do the rest of this. The params would come in via the `req.body` I know... but, not sure about the rest.

Below is their example from python

```
import hashlib

##
# Verify cverify from an ipn.
# @param post_params: A dictionary of all POST parameters from the notification
# @return: True if the cverify parameter is valid, false otherwise
def ipnVerification(post_params):
    secret_key = "YOUR SECRET KEY"
    pop = ""
    ipn_fields = []
    for key in post_params.keys():
        if key == "cverify":
            continue
        ipn_fields.append(key)
    ipn_fields.sort()
    for field in ipn_fields:
        pop += post_params[field] + "|"
    pop += secret_key
    return post_params["cverify"] == hashlib.sha1(pop).hexdigest()[:8].upper()
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var secretKey = 'My Secret Key';

module.exports = {
    validateRequest: function(req){
        var params = []
        for (param in req.body) {
            if (param == "cverify")
                continue;
            params.push(param);
        }

        params.sort();
        var pop = "";

        for (param in params) {
            pop += req.body.param + "|";
        }
        pop += secretKey;
        var cverify = req.body.cveryify;

        // do crypto stuff
        console.log(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly:

```
var secretKey = 'My Secret Key';

module.exports = {
  validateRequest : function(req) {
    /* shorter version of what you have already:
    var keys = Object.keys(req.body)
                .filter(function(key) { return key !== 'cverify'; })
                .sort();

    var pop = keys.map(function(key) {
      return body[key];
    }).join('|') + '|' + secretKey;
    */
    ...

    var sha1 = require('crypto').createHash('sha1');
    sha1.update(pop);
    var digest = sha1.digest('hex').substring(0, 8).toUpperCase();
    return digest === req.body.cverify;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra tid-bit on rewriting my code! I like it. When you `join('|')` you are adding an extra | - but whateva. This is great! Thank you. Would it be possible to do this easier with `crypto`'s built-in functions like `crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key)` or `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)` instead? Anyway, thanks again! I don't have the other service setup to send me tests yet but looks great!

Comment: @BRogers I think the extra `|` is required: `join` will only insert it between the keys, but not append an extra one as separator for `secretKey`

Comment: Oh crap! Your correct, I apologize :) - Thanks again for your help!